# Why isn't my phone charging?

Tags: battery, charging

I have a BLU Win Jr and the battery died. Now when I insert the charger it comes up with a question mark inside the battery, then goes to the Start screen and then back to the question mark. This happens constantly. Does anybody have any solutions?

Comment: This link may help you. http://forums.windowscentral.com/nokia-lumia-920/221259-battery-icon-doom.html